# Java applet logging

Tags: java, logging, java-6, java.util.logging

I'm not a Java developer so please remain calm if I write something incorrect.

I have a binary distributed Java applet which I decoded into quite readable source. My goal it to analyse activities of the applet. I see that the applet uses a lot of loggers to log actions, for example:

```
x.y.z.CONNECTION.LOG
x.y.z.GuiClient.GENERAL
```

etc.

But I don't see any of the messages in the Java console (however I see loads of other Java messages). 
I put to `logging.properties` the following lines:

```
.level = ALL
x.y.z.CONNECTION.LOG = ALL
x.y.z.GuiClient.GENERAL = ALL
```

with no effect.

What should I do to see messages logged by the loggers above?

If it could help I run MacOS 10.8, JDK 1.6.0, the applet starts in Mozilla 21.0
Please advise.

Comment: If it is a "standard" logging pattern, you would normally use levels like ERROR (most restrictive), INFO, DEBUG. DEBUG would showw all three. Don't know if that's your problem... On the other side, you might be able to configure the output of your logs, but being an Applet, you would not have much options other than the standard console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what the issue is. I made a mistake in `logging.properties`. I should have written:

```
x.y.z.CONNECTION.LOG.level = ALL
x.y.z.GuiClient.GENERAL.level = ALL
```